# Measure the TCP buffer in WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, sockets, tcp

Given a scenario of client - server communication, how do I measure and adjust the size of  **TCP buffer** for both client and server. I am looking for a c# code/direction, which does

a)  log TCP buffer size at each client and server

b)  alter the Tcp buffer size

**Client** : WPF application using C#.NET

**Server** : WCF with TCP binding (`ConcurrencyMode` is `Multiple` and  `InstanceContextMode` `PerCall`) with no duplex communication.

Comment: If you're talking about the buffer used by the communication channel, I don't think you can outside of the service host instantiation and the client instantiation - once those are set, you can't modify them.

Comment: @Tim, Yes. I want the channel buffer size. I wanted to set the size much before the host instantiate. This means, (a) size the buffer at client side (b) check with a pre-configured buffer value (server value) (c) if match do nothing and instantiate service proxy (d) else adjust buffer size and instantiate service proxy. I hope this make sense.

Comment: The only way I see this working is if you have a client proxy set up to get the pre-configured buffer value (step b).  If you use Proxy A to get the pre-configured buffer value from the service, you will not be able to adjust Proxy A's buffer in step d as needed.  If the buffer size doesn't match, you will need to create a new proxy with the desired buffer size.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks for your thread. First is first, can you please advice me on setting/getting tcp buffer size ? have you done similar before ? Will you be able to give me some head-start on this direction?